# JQuery CSS fails in IE 6, 8

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-2

here is code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function doit(){
         $('table td').each(function () {
         if ($(this).text().trim() != '')
             $(this).css("border", "1px groove white");
         });
     }
     doit();
</script>
```

this works in chrome and firefox.
BUT in IE 6 and 8 i have 'Object doesn't support this property or method'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn't with `.css()`, but with `.trim()`. IE doesn't have a native `.trim()` method for String.

You can use jQuery's `$.trim()` instead.

```
$.trim($(this).text())
```

- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/

So the `if()` statement would be:

```
if ( $.trim($(this).text()) != '' )
    $(this).css("border", "1px groove white");
```